# Add page id in html input on every page

Tags: wordpress, hook

I've written a WordPress plugin, which enables the admin to generate some html-code into the WYSIWYG editor. There are buttons in this html code which have a particular action - this is done via jQuery on the single page.

However, I need the page id as an input for jQuery; I want to add a hidden input field with the page id to every page.

Is there a hook which adds a particular html code to every page, so that i can access it via jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
function add_to_content($content) {

        $content .= "<input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='".get_the_ID()."' />";

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_to_content');
```